# Java implement multiple interfaces results in compilation error

Tags: maven, java-8

I'm building an application using Spring webmvc + data jpa with Java 8. I have entities inheritance like:

```
public class BaseEntity {...}
public class Report extends BaseEntity {...}
public class BlahBlah extends BaseEntity {...}
```

On the other hand, to enable CRUD operations on the entities, some repository interfaces are created as below:

```
/** 
 * Read-only repository.
 * See <a href="http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/12/18/handling-entities-inheritance-with-spring-data-jpa/">reference article</a>  
 */
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends Repository<T, Long> {
    T findOne(Long id);

    Iterable<T> findAll();

    Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);

    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pagable);
}
```

And for each inherited entity class there's a repository interface:

```
public interface ReportRepository extends BaseRepository<Report>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Report, Long> { }
```

The client code looks like this: (ReportController.java)

```
Report entity = reportRepo.findOne(id);
```

The application compiles and runs as we expected in eclipse. However when I try to package it using maven, there're several compilation errors, which are all similar to:

```
ReportController.java:[66,43] reference to findOne is ambiguous
both method findOne(ID) in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository 
and method findOne(java.lang.Long) in com.myapp.repositories.BaseRepository 
match
```

I don't quite understand the problem here. Yes, there's Type Erasure. But I also remember that if `class BaseRepository<T> extends Repository<T, Long>`, then `BaseRepository` will carry some information about the Type Argument passed to `Repository`. Isn't it?

If no, then how does JDK provides methods `java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass()` and `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()`?

If yes, then there should not be ambiguous methods because both interfaces have the same method `findOne(Long)`...

Any explaination? Thanks.

Updated:
For you to reproduce the issue with ease, I created a tiny project at https://github.com/guogin/problemapp. Please checkout.

Comment: Please show the configuration of your maven-compiler-plugin and any compiler related properties that you have set.

Comment: Type erasure is irrelevant. The compiler should always come to the conclusion that both supertypes have a `findOne(java.lang.Long)` method (at compile-time), even if `ReportRepository` was not a reifiable type. Eclipse’s compiler does that as expected, in either case.

Comment: On the other side, at bytecode level, the compiler has to decide whether it calls the one from `BaseRepository` or the one from `CrudRepository`, which do not have the same signature. We would have to refer to the JLS to resolve this case.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm back to answer the question myself.

Inspired by comment from Didier L, I tried to look up in the JLS. And now I have the answer.

First, [jls-§9.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1) states:

> An interface `I` inherits from its direct superinterfaces all abstract and default methods `m` for which all of the following are true:
>
> - `m` is a member of a direct superinterface, `J`, of `I`.
> - No method declared in `I` has a signature that is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of `m`.
> - There exists no method `m'` that is a member of a direct superinterface, `J'`, of `I` (`m` distinct from `m'`, `J` distinct from `J'`), such that `m'` overrides from `J'` the declaration of the method `m`.

In my sample code:

- `I` = `ReportRepository`
- `J1` = `BaseRepository<Report>`
- `m1` = `findOne(Long)` from `J1`
- `J2` = `PagingAndSortingRepository<Report, Long>`
- `m2` = `findOne(Long)` from `J2`
- Because `J2` is not superinterface of `J1` - So `I` actually inherits both `m1` and `m2` - that is to say, one `findOne(Long)` from `BaseRepository<Report>`, the other from `PagingAndSortingRepository<Report, Long>`.

The interface `ReportRepository` is itself syntax correct because both methods are inherit from super interfaces:

> [jls-§9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4)
>
> It is a compile-time error for the body of an interface to declare, explicitly or implicitly, two methods with override-equivalent signatures (§8.4.2). However, an interface may inherit several abstract methods with such signatures (§9.4.1).

And no clashes occurs.

In my example, the compilation error actually occurs at the caller method. So I further refer to [jls-§15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5): Choosing the Most Specific Method.

It turns out that, when compiling the code `ReportController` especially the call to `ReportRepository.findOne(Long)`, the compiler must find the more specific method between `m1` and `m2`. But then it find both are equally specific. Thus a compile-time error of 'ambiguous method call' occurs. That's what happened.

It turns out the eclipse compilation is not as standard as maven.

Comment: *not maven compiler*, but jdk one. maven only *uses* the compiler it is told to